# Is there an alternative to "type": "undefined" in JSON?

Tags: json, aws-api-gateway

I'm working with Amazon API Gateway. I am creating a model for an REST API.  The model gets hung up on:

```
"tiers": {
    "type": "array",
    "items": {
        "type": "undefined"
    }
}
```

The API data model uses [JSON schema draft 4](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-zyp-json-schema-04).

The error returned is:

> Invalid model specified: Validation Result: warnings : [], errors :
> [Invalid model schema specified]

Anyone run into this before?

Things I've tried:

1. Removing this property = script creates model
2. Changing "Undefined" to "null" = script creates model

The "null" seems like the right option but, I've not been able to back it up.  Some guidance and/or clarification would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Todd

Comment: What is your mean of "' not been able to back it up". You can modify the code model?

Comment: Articles from either Amazon or some other reputable source stating this is essential how you handle this.

Comment: Which api do you json for? I have not found it in the https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-deploy-api.html. You don't seem to be actually defining a schema for your data. refer to https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/models-mappings.html to re-define your model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't seem to be actually defining a schema for your data, refer to the [API gateway docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/models-mappings.html) to re-define your model.

undefined is not a valid json value, even though it is valid in javascript. From the [official json standard](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-404.pdf) (ECMA-404, Section 5):

> A JSON value can be an object, array, number, string, true, false, or
>   null.

**For json, use null instead of undefined: { "something": null }**

Using null instead of undefined is definitely not ideal, but it's a standard you can count on when consuming third-party services.

Comment: You are correct I did not define a schema for my data.  The problem is not with the schema.  The problem was with the "type": "undefined".  You essentially answered my questions. Thanks!